# Will multiple connection increase internet speed?

Tags: linux, networking

If i have a cable connection and a wireless connection at the same time, will that increase download/upload speed? I use Kubuntu linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use both the cable and wireless at the same time to act like one, big, faster connection? That's called bonding or trunking and you're looking for something like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

Of course, this requires that both your cable and wireless use separate connections to your ISP, otherwise it's not going to make a difference. In practice, your best bet is probably to just use the cable connection alone and get a faster connection from your ISP. It's a lot less hassle.

Answer (score -1):

No wireless is slower the cable, The bandwidth of a cable is relitive high (100mb/s) and the problem is not a network but a ISP (Internet Provider)

http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2127297